# jquery sortable that can also group items together

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I need a jquery sortable with the following functionality:

1. Sort items by drag and drop (which is the easy part)
2. Group and ungroup items (which is the part that I can not figure out).

The process works like this:

*The user provides a list of items.* I use that list to build a sortable unordered list  using jquery.

Example:

- A
- B
- C
- D

*The user then needs to use this sortable to rank the items from best to worst.*  The user needs to be able to group together items that are equivalent (e.g. same rank)

Example:

- A
- B C
- D

Desired UI flow:

- Handles and placeholders are used to move items in the sortable (again, easy, but I am not sure how to do the rest)
- A placeholder is visible when a user hovers over an existing item so that the items could be grouped together. A group of items are a single li as shown above.
- The user could click and drag one handle to move the entire group and another handle to remove an item from the group and place it in a new spot in the list (as an individual by building a new li or move it from one group to another group adding it to an existing li).

Things that I have tried:

- *nested sortable plugins*,  I could not get them to do what I needed.  I do not have an outline or folder structure, I want all items to be on the same level.
- *connected sortables*, I do not know how many sortables to create in the beginning, I have no idea if a user will want to group items together and how many groups there will be in the end. Overall, this approach was not working.
- *click and place* , I wrote a click event for an item.  When a user clicks on an item, all of the possible placeholders become visible, and then the user selects a placeholder and the item is moved to that placeholder.  It is working ok, but I would really like to use a more intuitive drag and drop.

I am open to other approaches or html structures for my list if it will work as I described in the beginning.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly I think that I have some solution for your problem.

First of all you should use some server side language for this (for example php) and for making a groups and items you should use some database (for example mysql). 
In your database you need to create two tables Items and Groups, and make relation between them one (group) to many (items). 
When you do that, you need to get groups and items with your server side language and display it for your sortable part.

You need to display your groups and items like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $groups; $i++)
{
    echo '<ul id="group_'.$i.'" group_id="'.$groups[$i]->getId().'" class="droptrue">';
    echo '<li class="disabled">'.$name_of_group.'</li>'; - this item needs to be disabled for drag and drop and you can do that for any individual item with sortable ui plugin
    for($j = 0; $j < count($items); $j++)
    {
        echo '<li id="'.$items[$j]->getId().'" class="enabled ui-state-highlight">'.$item.'</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

This is one way you can group your items and manipulate with them.

And this is javascript code for manipulating with items.

```
$(function() {
  $( "ul.droptrue" ).sortable({
    connectWith: "ul",
    items: "> li.enabled",
    start: function(event, ui){
        var parent = ui.item.parent();
        parent.addClass('modified_ul');
    },
    stop: function(event, ui){
        var parent = ui.item.parent();
        parent.addClass('modified_ul');
    },
    update: function(event, ui){
        $('#update_channel_order').removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('button_big_disabled');
  }
});

$('#update_channel_order').click(function(){

    if (!$(this).attr('disabled'))
    {
      $('.modified_ul').each(function(){

          var array_for_db = [];
          var group_id = $(this).attr('group_id');

          var lis_enabled = $(this).children('.enabled');
          for(i = 0; i < lis_enabled.length; i++)
          {
              var id = lis_enabled[i].attributes['id'].value;
              var obj = {};
              obj['id'] = id;
              obj['index'] = i;
              array_for_db.push(obj);
          }
        $.ajax({
            url: '/path/to/your/function/group_id/' + group_id + '/values/' + JSON.stringify(array_for_db),
            beforeSend: function() {
              $('#loader_channel_order').show();
            },
            success: function(data) {
              location.reload();
            },
            complete: function() {
              $('#loader_channel_order').hide();
            }
        });
      });
      $(this).addClass('button_big_disabled').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I have a db backend and I am successfully displaying the order of the items, but I need a way for the user to update that order as I described above.  Any ideas on how to allow a user to do that?

Comment: I have a version of that, but I do not know if this would be an appropriate solution for you. Anyway, I will put my code in answer. 
If you don't have benefit of it, maybe someone else do.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I do not think that is addresses my issues.  I do not know the number of groups in advance, the groups have to be created and deleted dynamically.  If you have any thoughts, I would appreciate that, if not I appreciate your thoughts so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought. Can you use optgroup to group the values?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I though that opt groups were for <select> tags?  The user needs to reorder the list.  I am not sure how I could use optgroups, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I would think you could just make the all the other sortable elements (besides the one being moved) into droppables. Then you would be able to drop the moving one onto any of the other ones. Then add a mechanism to ungroup and some bookkeeping and dom maintenance and bobs your uncle. I have no idea how nicely sortable and droppable will play together, but I would hope it'd be okay. We are supposed to build stuff with this stuff right? Well, that's where I'd start anyway.